# Merge two regexp

Tags: php, regex

```
function regexp($text){
   $text = preg_replace('#!test=#', '', $text);
   $text = preg_replace('#@test=#', '', $text);
   return $text;
}
```

How can i merge this regexp? They differ only ! and @. In my example is error, and this not working. I would like simply:

```
$a = 'asdf!test=wer';
$b = '232@test=dsf';
```

change to:

```
$a = 'asdfwer';
$b = '232dsf';
```

with regexp.

Comment: `preg_replace('#[!@]test=#', '', $text)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like so should match both: `#(!|@)test=#`. If you will have more signs (other than `!` and `@`, replacing it with something like this: `#[!@]test=#` (as suggested by @DCoder) will yield a cleaner regex.

Essentially the pipe (`|`) in regular expression language denotes an `OR`. So essentially, I am saying match the string `test=` if it is prefixed by an `!` or an `@` sign.

Comment: Nice answer than me...you deserve it

Answer (score 0):

Try `preg_replace` with an array of regex with an array of replaces like

```
$text = preg_replace(array('#!test=#' , '#@test=#'),array('' , ''), $text);
```